# creating a CAP file with JCDK

Tags: applet, converters, smartcard, javacard

Since starting to use Java Cards, I've been able to upload and run applets from provided .cap files using PCSC, CCID, and GPshell.  I'd like to make and upload my own applets but I've had trouble converting java files to .cap files using the Java Card Development Kit from Oracle.  The format given by the the User's Manual is:

> converter [options] package_name package_AID major_version.minor_version

I have a helloWorld.java file saved to my Desktop - it's the only file there.  The "classdir" option should set the root directory where the converter command looks for classes.  Based on the User's Manual and examples from elsewhere online I have:

> converter -classdir Desktop HelloWorld.java 0×01:0×02:0×03:0×04:0×05:0×06:0×07:0×08:0×09:0×00:0×00 1.0

the result of that command is:

> error: invalid AID 0×01:0×02:0×03:0×04:0×05:0×06:0×07:0×08:0×09:0×00:0×00.

switching to another AID I'd seen used in examples, I ran:

> converter -classdir Desktop HelloWorld.java 0xF2:0x34:0x12:0x34:0x56:0x10:0x10:0x00 1.0

which returned

> error: input class directory Desktop/HelloWorld/java not found.

If someone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong I'd really appreciate it.
    Many Thanks

Comment: Running the converter on class files instead of source files may help for starters.

Comment: This link can help you to make a .cap file from a .java file with JCDK installed on Eclipse. I suggest you to start here! this way is easier than the way that you selected :)
 http://eclipse-jcde.sourceforge.net/user-guide.htm

Comment: you can find  "how to add JCDK to Eclipse?" here :

http://eclipse-jcde.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for the responses owlstead and @abraham .  I figured out after posting this that I had to compile the source files before I could convert them.  I've done that, but now I'm having trouble with the converter not finding the export file I give in my .opt file.  As I understand it abraham , the eclipse JCDE is basically a wrapper for Oracle's JCDK; If I set up the JCDE, wouldn't it run into the same errors as I am?

Comment: I set up the JCDE and was able to generate a .cap file after changing the java compiler settings.  Thanks!

Comment: @pineapplevendor your welcome. so, please add an answer here contain of what did you do to solve your problem and select it as the right answer (for people whom read your question in future ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Using the JCDE Plugin with Eclipse was my resolution to this problem.

Installation and setup instructions can be found at this link:

http://eclipse-jcde.sourceforge.net/

and a user guide for how to use JCDE with Eclipse can be found at this link:

[eclipse-jcde.sourceforge.net/user-guide.htm .](http://eclipse-jcde.sourceforge.net/user-guide.htm)

To create .CAP files I followed the  user guide and also changed to the compiler settings for the project by right clicking on the project, selecting properties, navigating to Java Compiler, and choosing compiler compliance level 1.4.
As a side note, if you are using a 2.2.1 Java Card you might not be able to upload your .cap file.  The solution I found to create .cap files compliant with 2.2.1 is I replaced the contents of the 2.2.2 jcdk home directory with the contents of a 2.2.1 jcdk home directory.